# Max width for content view of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

A common pattern in UI is to maximize the size of the view up to some point and after that fill the rest of its superview with the spaces.

When using AutoLayout, it can be achieved easily with width <= X constraint. But when using this with UICollectionView, the scroll area matches the size of UICollectionView, so the sides are unscrollable which is unwanted for me.

So, the only way I found to achieve the behavior is to use the proper layout inside the cells themselves. I consider this as a not very good design decision (especially when you have multiple cells). But are there any alternatives available?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Are you talking about a Horizontal scrolling collection view? Or vertical? What do you mean by *"the sides are unscrollable"*? Maybe show a screen-shot of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: In my case, that is a horizontal collection view. If you constraint the view with width <= X, the sides of the screen will be outside of the view and they can’t be used to scroll the view, which is not what I want. So I’m trying to find a way to have that empty spaces on each side of the view, but to also be able to scroll the collectionView by touching them.

Comment: OK - just to be clear... you have a horizontal collection view that is less that the width of its superview, and you want to be able to scroll by touching and dragging from the areas to the left and right? As in this pic (the red dashed-outline is showing where you want to be able to drag)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/er870.png

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this by subclassing `UICollectionView` and implementing `hitTest(_:with:)`.

What we'll do is extend the "touch area" wider than the collection view itself:

```
class ExtendedCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        if self.bounds.contains(point) {
            // touch is inside self.bounds, so
            //  send it on to super (i.e. "normal" behavior)
            //  so we can select a cell on tap
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }

        if self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -self.frame.origin.x, dy: 0).contains(point) {
            // touch is outside self.bounds, but
            //  it IS inside bounds extended left and right, so
            //  capture the touch for self
            return self
        }

        // touch was outside self.bounds (and outside our extended bounds), so
        //  send it on to super (i.e. "normal" behavior)
        //  so the rest of the view hierarchy (buttons, etc)
        //      can receive the gesture
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        
    }
    
}
```

You can now use `ExtendedCollectionView` just as you would use `UICollectionView`, except you'll be able to scroll it starting from left or right, outside of its bounds.

Here's a complete example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = []
    
    // we'll use these colors for the cell backgrounds
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
        .systemPink, .systemYellow, .systemTeal,
    ]
    
    // our "extended collection view"
    var collectionView: ExtendedCollectionView!
    
    let cellSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 100)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Extended CollectionView"
        
        // always respect the safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // let's add a "background" image view, sized to fit the view
        //  so we can easily see the reults
        if let img = UIImage(named: "sampleBKG") {
            let v = UIImageView()
            v.image = img
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            view.sendSubviewToBack(v)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])
        }
        
        // fill myData array with 20 strings
        //  of different lengths to show this
        //  works with dynamic width cells
        let strs: [String] = [
            "Short",
            "Bit Longer",
            "Much Longer String",
        ]
        for i in 0..<20 {
            myData.append("C: \(i) \(strs[i % strs.count])")
        }
        
        
        // set the flow layout properties
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 100)
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            fl.minimumLineSpacing = 8
            fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8

        // create an instance of ExtendedCollectionView
        collectionView = ExtendedCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        // let's make the collection view
        //  80% of the width of the view's safe area
        let cvWidthPercent = 0.8
        
        // let's add a label below our custom view
        //  the same percentage width, so we can
        //  easily see the layout
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.text = "\(cvWidthPercent * 100)%"
        view.addSubview(v)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's put our collection view
            // 80-pts from the top
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            // centered Horizontally
            collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            //  height equal to cell Height
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellSize.height),
            // 80% of the width of the safe area
            collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: cvWidthPercent),

            // constrain label 8-pts below the collection view
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            // centered Horizontally
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            // same percentage width
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: cvWidthPercent),
            
        ])
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.register(MyDynamicCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cvCell")
        
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cvCell", for: indexPath) as! MyDynamicCVCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item % colors.count]
        cell.label.text = myData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Did Select Cell At:", indexPath)
    }
}
```

**a simple dynamic-width cell**

```
class MyDynamicCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

[image]

When you run it, you'll see that you can scroll horizontally, even if you start dragging from the left or right of the cells.